# delete query by matching two attributes

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE deleteProcFood(id IN food_item.R_ID%TYPE,
item_name IN food_item.ITEM_NAME%TYPE)IS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM food_item
WHERE food_item.R_ID = id  AND
food_item.ITEM_NAME = item_name;

COMMIT;

END;
/
```

This is a procedure to delete by matching with two attributes values but it delete values by matching with only R_ID. Here, the matching with value after AND is not working.How can I solve this problem???

Comment: Is it because item_name is same as ITEM_NAME? May be try changing item_name as PIN_ITEM_NAME (Procedure 'IN' Item Name)

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE deleteProcFood(PIN_ID IN food_item.R_ID%TYPE,
PIN_item_name IN food_item.ITEM_NAME%TYPE)IS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM food_item
WHERE food_item.R_ID = PIN_ID   AND
food_item.ITEM_NAME = PIN_item_name;

COMMIT;

END;
/
```

I doubt if `ITEM_NAME = ITEM_NAME` always returns true. Hence trying to change the parameter variable names.

Comment: @PossessedHamid: Please accept as answer by ticking the grey tick box  beside this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to always alias everything, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE deleteProcFood(id IN food_item.R_ID%TYPE,
item_name IN food_item.ITEM_NAME%TYPE)IS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM food_item
WHERE food_item.R_ID = deleteProcFood.id  AND
food_item.ITEM_NAME = deleteProcFood.item_name;

COMMIT;

END;
/
```